# Tamanho de Banco de Dados com CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, codeigniter-3

Boa tarde, pessoal! Como faço para saber a quantidade de linhas de um Banco de Dados, utilizando o framework CodeIgniter 3? Preciso controlar a quantidade de dados a serem inseridos, para que não ultrapasse um certo limite.

Exemplo para compreender minha dúvida: vamos supor que eu queira, no máximo, somente 100 dados no BD. Se eu quiser adicionar mais um, isso não será possível, pois ultrapassou o limite que estabeleci. Agradeço, desde já, a quem puder ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa contar o número de registros em uma tabela ou no banco completo, todas tabelas? Caso seja em uma tabela específica:

```
<?php

public function conta_tabela(){

    $query = $this->db->get('tabela');

    echo 'Existem '.$query->num_rows().' registros nessa tabela';
}

?>
```